# Check if html text exists within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

would really appreciate any help. I have an iframe displayed in a webpage and I want to do a search for a specific text string within this iframe, say "Go Bananas" - to check if a match is found

Now if I use `$("#HTML").contents()[0]` in Chrome Dev Tools console I am able to navigate the entire DOM object to the point where the text is located in `<span>Go Bananas</span>` ... Path will not necessarily always be the same

▼ `<iframe src="http"//localhost/site/theemmbededsite.html>` 
  ▼ `#document` 
  ▼ `<html>` 
   ▼ `<body>` 
    ▼ `<div>` 
     ▼ `<span> Go Bananas </span>`

My question is : how do I Check if this text "Go Bananas" exists in this object `$("#HTML").contents()[0]` and return a `true`or `false`

I have tried a bunch of jquery functions but to no avail.. Will appreciate any help

Comment: you want hierarchy of found match?i am not getting whatyou want.

Comment: I want to check if the iframe contains the words "Go Bananas" .. basically a true or false

Comment: please give my answer a try and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Search and get length then put condition based on length.

```
if($("iframe").contents().text().search("Go Bananas") > -1)
  //found -- do stuff
else
  //not-found do stuff
```

Use jQuery `contents().text().search()` method.

Comment: if i do `$("iframe").contents().text()` I get jibberish HTML in return (a type of error messag to display on the page). You see the path of the iframe is dynamic - so I use a div container ` <div id='HTML' ></div>` and then do `$("#HTML").append('<iframe src = ' +theURI + ' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>');` in the code . The closest I have come is to use `$("#HTML").contents()[0]`

Comment: means? are you getting content of iframe in $("#HTML").contents()[0]?

Comment: Yes sir .. So I tried the following

`var content = $("#HTML").contents()[0];
$(content).contents().text().search("Go Bananas")
`


result : -1

Comment: Please note that the [`String#search(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method is not a jQuery function. Only the [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) functions are.